# Get noticed when other app tries to access camera on Android

Tags: android, camera

I am working on the app that uses camera and mic in background mode. Obviously, when my app is active other camera apps (like Camera) will not work as the camera is held by my app.

Is there any way to get notified when the other app tries to open camera (if the camera is held by my app)?
I want my app to show some popup or notification when any other app tries to get camera (I think it will be more user-friendly to show some notice then to rely on other app's error messages)

Comment: I guess that the camera (or any other device/sensor) is held by the foreground app. Not necessarily yours.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi - well, I need to get notified on other apps trying to access camera only when MY app holds camera. Edited my question to be mo clear

Comment: My doubt is... are you sure that your app locks the camera?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. My app getting and releasing camera only under certain situations. When my app is active I cannot use Camera app on my phone. See more: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#release-camera

Comment: Can you be plz more specific and clear about what you want or what problem you are facing?As I thnk from your que that You are not releasing Camera instance from your activity so other apps unable to make work with Camera.

Comment: I see. I don't know if the MediaRecorder object has a mean to tell you "someone is trying to initialize me". I didn't find the evidence of any such event listener.

Comment: Exactly. But my app needs to hold camera to do its job. So I want my app to be able to notify user that it is holding the camera when user tries to take a pic or to do anything else with camera

Comment: Then you could do **the opposite**. Have your app setting an icon or a text in the notification area saying "The camera is locked by [App Name]".

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my plan B if I will be unable to find a way to get notified by another app that the camera is needed

Comment: Yes, I think it's not feasible. Therefore, the workaround I proposed.